# Unity Failed to Repackage Resources

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

I was trying to integrate Admob into my unity game. I imported the Google Play Games plugin and the Admob Plugin , but I have been getting this error for the past couple days.

```html
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\Tau\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Tau/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:android.support.v4 -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-clearcut-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.8.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.0.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.0.0\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:111: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:48: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.internal.widget.DialogTitle>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:77: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:96: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:64: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_lines for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:43: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <include>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:33: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_media for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <Chronometer>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_part_chronometer for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <DateTimeView>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:layout/notification_template_part_time for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\drawable\abc_textfield_search_material.xml:19: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:state_activated from <item>
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.0.0\res\drawable\abc_textfield_search_material.xml: note: using v11 attributes; synthesizing resource com.CasualGames.CoinDrop:drawable/abc_textfield_search_material for configuration v11.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res\values\values.xml:33: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.4.0\res\values\values.xml:3: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.4.0\res\values\values.xml:21: error: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res\values\values.xml:47: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.4.0\res\values\values.xml:21: error: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Tau\Documents\Coin Drop\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.8.0\res\values\values.xml:55: Original attribute defined here.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I paid to solve this issue , but the solution is simple. Delete the google play services folder , delete the play -services 9.4.0 files and support v23. in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing **Google Play Services**, which is a separate package from the two you are using and it is a dependency. You will need to download it either through Android Studio or some other location and add it into your project folders. See this question here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1190674/missing-libraries-in-google-play-services-revision.html

Comment: I downloaded the GPS and deleted the stuff in the manifest the guy said. Still getting the error.